# Why can't a subclass of a subclass access protected member of its ancestor?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class `Animal`, which has a subclass `Dog`, which has a subclass `BigDog`. The class `Animal` has a `protected int legs`. I am unable to access `legs` in the `BigDog` class functions or constructor.

```cpp
class Animal {
protected:
    int legs = 0;
    Color eyeColor = Color(0,0,0);
public:
    virtual string getSound() const = 0;
};

class Dog : Animal {
public:
    string getSound() const override {
        string sound = "";
        int legI = legs;
        while (legI-- > 0) {
            sound+=" *step* ";
        }
        sound+="BARK";
        return sound;
    }
    Dog() : Animal() {
        legs = 4;
        eyeColor = Color(200,128,0);
    }
};

class BigDog : Dog {
public:
    //use the initializer of dog
    BigDog() : Dog() {
        legs = 4;
    }
    string getSound() const override {
        string sound = "";
        int legI = legs;
        while (legI-- > 0) {
            sound+=" *step* ";
        }
        sound+="BOOF BOOF";
        return sound;
    }
};
```

This code gives "error: ‘int Animal::legs’ is protected" when setting or reading legs from BigDog

Comment: You have private inheritance.  That's not what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
class Dog : Animal { … };
```

what you're really writing is

```
class Dog : private Animal { … };
```

because the default access specifier for classes defined with *class-key* `class` is `private` [[class.access.base]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#base-2) (fancy way of saying: if you have a `class` that class will inherit everything to be private unless you explicitly say otherwise). Private inheritance means all protected and public members of the base class will be private in the derived class. Since `Dog` inherited all the `Animal` stuff privately, it's not accessible to `BigDog` anymore (which, by the way, also inherits all the `Dog` stuff privately). What you most likely wanted to write is

```
class Dog : public Animal { … };
```

and

```
class BigDog : public Dog { … };
```

Note: if you had a `struct`, the default would be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using private inheritance, which implies that every inherited member becomes private. You want public inheritance.

```
class Dog : public Animal {
...
class BigDog : public Dog {
```

Note the keyword `public` here, which ensures that public members remain public and protected members remain protected. The access specifier for inheritance specifies the *maximum* visibility of any inherited member, so when it's private everything will be private. And, like with members of `class` classes, if you don't specify, the inheritance will assume that you mean private. More on that [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).